# Flutter blank screen when using Form with TextFormField

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield

I am making a login screen like I have many times, but I keep running into this issue and don't know what to do. There are two `TextFormFields`, inside a `Column`, inside a `Form` like this

```
  Widget loginForm() {
    return Form(
        key: _loginFormKey,
        child: Flexible(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _emailController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  suffix: Icon(Icons.mail_outline_rounded, color: Colors.red),
                  labelText: "Email",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF7FCCDC))),
                ),
                validator: (email) {
                  return null;
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _passController,
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  suffix: Icon(Icons.lock_outline, color: Colors.red),
                  labelText: "Password",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF7FCCDC))),
                ),
                validator: (password) {
                  return null;
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
```

This widget is put in the following scaffold:

```
        Padding(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 175, left: 35, right: 35, bottom: 50),
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 300,
              width: 250,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Color(0xFFFCFBF4).withOpacity(0.5),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 15),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text('Sign In',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20, color: Color(0xFF6B6FAB))),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      loginForm(),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

When the `loginForm()` widget is removed, the screen launches as it should. However, when it is there, the screen launches blank white. I've tried taking all the customization out of the `TextFormFields` and putting them in containers with restricted sizes but that didn't change anything. This is no different from the way I've done the forms in the past and there are no errors. What is the issue?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignInScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignInScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SignInScreen> createState() => _SignInScreenState();
}

class _SignInScreenState extends State<SignInScreen> {
  final _loginFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget background() {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
        Color(0xFF7157A0),
        Color(0xFF6B6FAB),
        Color(0xFF6C74B4),
        Color(0xFF697CB4)
      ], stops: [
        0.25,
        0.5,
        0.75,
        1
      ], begin: Alignment.topCenter)),
    );
  }

  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passController = TextEditingController();

  Widget loginForm() {
    return Form(
      key: _loginFormKey,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _emailController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              suffix: Icon(Icons.mail_outline_rounded, color: Colors.red),
              labelText: "Email",
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF7FCCDC))),
            ),
            validator: (email) {
              return null;
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _passController,
            obscureText: true,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              suffix: Icon(Icons.lock_outline, color: Colors.red),
              labelText: "Password",
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF7FCCDC))),
            ),
            validator: (password) {
              return null;
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      children: [
        background(),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 55),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Image.asset('assets/logo.png', height: 100),
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              Text('GLOBE',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 40,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      color: Color(0xFF7FCCDC)))
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 175, left: 35, right: 35, bottom: 50),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFFFCFBF4).withOpacity(0.5),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 15),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text('Sign In',
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Color(0xFF6B6FAB))),
                    ],
                  ),
                  loginForm()
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove flexible here and add mainAxisSize min to the column widget. A flexible inside a column without bounds will break the ui

```
return Form(
        key: _loginFormKey,
      //child: Flexible( //remove this widget
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          )
);
```

Your layout should be something like this

```
Scaffold(
  body: Container(
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
   height: MediaQuery.of(context).height,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
     image: DecorationImage(
       image: AssetImage('image path here'),
     )
    )
   child: Column(
    children: []//place widgets here
   )
  )
)
```

Now if the widgets are long enough to move over the height of device wrap the column with SingleChildScrollView

**EDIT**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: SignInScreen());
  }
}

class SignInScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignInScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SignInScreen> createState() => _SignInScreenState();
}

class _SignInScreenState extends State<SignInScreen> {
  final _loginFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passController = TextEditingController();

  Widget loginForm() {
    return Form(
      key: _loginFormKey,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _emailController,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              suffix: Icon(Icons.mail_outline_rounded, color: Colors.red),
              labelText: "Email",
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF7FCCDC))),
            ),
            validator: (email) {
              return null;
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _passController,
            obscureText: true,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              suffix: Icon(Icons.lock_outline, color: Colors.red),
              labelText: "Password",
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF7FCCDC))),
            ),
            validator: (password) {
              return null;
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
        Color(0xFF7157A0),
        Color(0xFF6B6FAB),
        Color(0xFF6C74B4),
        Color(0xFF697CB4)
      ], stops: [
        0.25,
        0.5,
        0.75,
        1
      ], begin: Alignment.topCenter)),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 55),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Image.network(
                    'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/jpg-file-icon-logo-element-illustration-design-155443757.jpg',
                    height: 100),
                SizedBox(width: 5),
                Text('GLOBE',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 40,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Color(0xFF7FCCDC)))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 35),
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 40),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xFFFCFBF4).withOpacity(0.5),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(height: 15),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text('Sign In',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20, color: Color(0xFF6B6FAB))),
                        ],
                      ),
                      loginForm()
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense but I just tried this and I'm still met with a blank screen. If you haven't already, can you please look at the second part of the code where the `loginForm` widget is used and see if something is wrong there?

Comment: Sorry, I know my code is a bit confusing, so I'll try to explain it here. The scaffold is a stack of three layers: background, logo/app name, and on top is the container with the column and `loginForm()`. The container is not the full-screen size which is why I used padding outside of it instead of height and width. I did try adding height and width but that didn't fix the issue. Basically, it's `Padding`>`Container`>`Column`>`loginForm()`.

Comment: Got it. Also here you don't need a row. Row(
                    children: [
                      loginForm(),
                    ],
                  ) you can directly add loginForm here

Comment: I just added all of the screen's current code to the bottom of the question if you are willing to try and reproduce it. If not I understand and thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyHome extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final _loginFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          background(context),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 55),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: const [
                // Image.asset('assets/logo.png', height: 100),
                SizedBox(width: 5),
                Text('GLOBE',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 40,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Color(0xFF7FCCDC)))
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 175, left: 35, right: 35, bottom: 50),
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: const Color(0xFFFCFBF4).withOpacity(0.5),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 15),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: const [
                        Text('Sign In',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 20, color: Color(0xFF6B6FAB))),
                      ],
                    ),
                    loginForm(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget loginForm() {
    return Form(
      key: _loginFormKey,
      child: Flexible(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _emailController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                suffix: Icon(Icons.mail_outline_rounded, color: Colors.red),
                labelText: "Email",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF7FCCDC))),
              ),
              validator: (email) {
                return null;
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: _passController,
              obscureText: true,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                suffix: Icon(Icons.lock_outline, color: Colors.red),
                labelText: "Password",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF7FCCDC))),
              ),
              validator: (password) {
                return null;
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget background(context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
          Color(0xFF7157A0),
          Color(0xFF6B6FAB),
          Color(0xFF6C74B4),
          Color(0xFF697CB4)
        ], stops: [
          0.25,
          0.5,
          0.75,
          1
        ], begin: Alignment.topCenter),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of making a separate class for the `loginForm()` widget I made it like this: `Widget loginForm() {<Form is in here>}`. If it helps, this error is also showing up `minimumViewportInset cannot be larger than frame`, I'm not sure if it's related

Comment: It is like the error-causing widget is the background(), Widget, can you add the code to the background.

Comment: I just added it

Comment: I actually added all of the screens code to the bottom of the question so you can try to reproduce the issue if you're willing to.

Comment: I've edited my answer, I don't seem to be getting any errors.

Comment: Interesting... the only difference I see in our code is that you're not using a stateful widget but even when I run your code copy and pasted it gives me a white screen. Can you try running the complete screen code that I added to the bottom of the question and see if it works for you?

Comment: I just ran it and got the desired output, no white screen.

Comment: I don't know how it's not working for me then but thank you for trying. I'm gonna try a different simulator.